# How to send links in mail Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I send mail with Laravel:

Mail\User.php

```
return $this->from('admin@example.com', 'Admin')
        ->subject('Register in example')
        ->markdown('mails.user')
        ->with([
            'name' => 'Register in example',
            'link' => $link,
        ]);
```

mails\user.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')

Link:
<a href="{{$link}}">{{$link}}</a>
@endcomponent
```

Message arrives in the inbox:

```
Link:
<a href="http://...">http://...</a>
```

Only on gmail, when I enter a regular link it works, i.e.

mails\user.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')

Link:
{{$link}}
@endcomponent
```

After first line Laravel creates  `tag. 
I don't know why, I write text in the same tag @component('mail::message'):`

```
@component('mail::message')
**Hi**,



Twój indywidualny link do sprawdzania udziałów:
    [{{$linkActivation}}]({{$linkActivation}})
```

@endcomponent

"Hi" works, but link not.
In inbox sth like:

```
<p>Hi</p>
<pre><code>rest of the text</code></pre>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to send clicable link?

Comment: And what's not working?

Comment: Message arrives in the inbox with <a> tag as text

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Not yet. arrives:
"[https://...](https://...)"

Comment: Are you using markdown syntax?

Comment: I think yes, first line works, but other not.

Comment: After first line Laravel creates <code> tag. I don't know why, I write text in the same tag @component('mail::message')

Comment: Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using markdown not HTML in your Mail\User.php: `->markdown('mails.user')`

You need to use [markdown syntax](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links) to send a link, `[link text](URL)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was in spaces.
https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown/issues/119#issuecomment-460869699

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue with Mail markdown for link and it's worked for me:

```
    <br >
    @if ($order->hasPostalCode)
        <a href="{{$url}}">Click here</a>
    @else
        some text here
    @endif
```

Here `<br>` helps, without br it was printing raw HTML, and with

`[Click Here]({{ $url }})` was printing button but after it was showing raw HTML code with table tag